# Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 467

Tags: product, linux, magento-2.0.1

[image]

Can you help me? please, I want to know , how to fixed this error in magento 2.0.46 in ubuntu 14.04 Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your

```
[MAGENTO_ROOT_DIR]/app/design/frontend/default/etc/view.xml
```

for space between or after the numerical values, If any please remove them.

Comment: what is remove this file (view.xml)